# coffeescript - Why does this always output as '1'?

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript

How come this always outputs as "1" even if randomArea isn't North?

```
if randomArea = "North"
    id.innerHTML = "1"
else if randomArea = "South"
    id.innerHTML = "2"
else if randomArea = "East"
    id.innerHTML = "3"
else if randomArea = "West"
    id.innerHTML = "4"
else if randomArea = "Central"
    id.innerHTML = "5"
else if randomArea = ""
    id.innerHTML = "6"
```

Comment: `=` & `==` are different.

Comment: By `=` you are telling the computer to put `"North"` into `randomArea`. It's called "assignment"
You should use `==` to check if value of `randomArea` is `"North"`

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the `=` is an assignment operator, which will always assign the value, which the if-statement will evaluate for truthiness.  In this case "North" is a non-empty string, which is truthy, so `id.innerHTML` is assigned its value of `"1"`. The equality operator, `==`, should be used instead.

```
if randomArea = "North"       // <-- here
    id.innerHTML = "1"
else if randomArea = "South"
    id.innerHTML = "2"
else if randomArea = "East"
    id.innerHTML = "3"
else if randomArea = "West"
    id.innerHTML = "4"
else if randomArea = "Central"
    id.innerHTML = "5"
else if randomArea = ""
    id.innerHTML = "6"
```

You need to change all equality conditions to evaluate truthiness, rather than assign values, which would always resolve as `true` with non-empty strings:

```
if randomArea == "North"            // <-- here
    id.innerHTML = "1"
else if randomArea == "South"       // <-- here
    id.innerHTML = "2"
else if randomArea == "East"        // <-- here
    id.innerHTML = "3"
else if randomArea == "West"        // <-- here
    id.innerHTML = "4"
else if randomArea == "Central"     // <-- here
    id.innerHTML = "5"
else if randomArea == ""            // <-- here
    id.innerHTML = "6"
```

Note:

- the `// <-- here` most likely need to be removed for valid CoffeeScript

Comment: this doesnt seem to be working. is this correct? ```if randomArea == "North"
    id.innerHTML = "1"
else if randomArea == "South"
    id.innerHTML = "2"
else if randomArea == "East"
    id.innerHTML = "3"
else if randomArea == "West"
    id.innerHTML = "4"
else if randomArea == "Central"
    id.innerHTML = "5"
else if randomArea == ""
    id.innerHTML = "6"

Comment: @sudocode1 it's right; but don't copy/paste the code above, I believe the `// <-- here` is invalid CoffeeScript